Android Studio/Java - AAPT: error: attribute adUnitID Not Found
Okay, So I've been beating my head against the desk for two days trying to resolve this problem and I'm at a loss. Hoping it's something simple, but not sure.
I have an Android project making use of Google AdMob. I've followed all of the instructions from the AdMob developer site. When building my project it fails with the following error:


Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/user12345/Developer/Android Studio Projects/MyApp/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml","position":{"startLine":213}}],"original":"ERROR: /Users/user12345/Developer/Android Studio Projects/MyApp//app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:214: AAPT: error: attribute adUnitID (aka com.someorg.MyApp.debug:adUnitID) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}


Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
Android resource linking failed
ERROR: /Users/user12345/Developer/Android Studio Projects/MyApp/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:214: AAPT: error: attribute adUnitID (aka com.someorg.myapp.debug:adUnitID) not found.

Clearly it's pointing at the XML file. In my XML, this is what I have:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#000000"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitID="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

For some reason the resource linker isn't finding adUnitID. This my app-level build.gradle file:
android {
namespace 'com.someorg.myapp'
compileSdk 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.someorg.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode 7
    versionName '1.0.7'
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildFeatures {
    buildConfig true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        debuggable false
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        debuggable true
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
dependencies {
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.11.0"))
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.9.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.7.2'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.3'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.3'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:23.3.0' 
}
}

And this is the portion of the Manifest.XML file that contains the :
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-################~##########"/>

(I have redacted the app-id in the above)
I have no idea what to do at this point. I might try building a new sample project and see if I can get just an adview working.

I've never used it, but it looks like it ends in a lowercase d. That is, ads:adUnitId. Also, not strictly relevant to the issue, but your app and ads prefixes both point to the same app namespace, so you could just use one everywhere, and get rid of the other.

Holy crap... that was the problem! Such a dumb mistake on my part! Thank you!

Per Mike M. - the problem was a capital D in this line of XML:
ads:adUnitID="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"

which I changed to:
ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"

And this resolved the problem.
